# Issue with using WorksheetFunction.Substitute in combination with Offset

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset, substitution

I need to write a function to carry out a number of substitutions into a string, based on looking up values in the sheet.

My intention is to iterate over a list of substitution pairs in the sheet and calling the workbook function 'substitute' for each iteration.

```
Function multiSub(original As Range, replaceList As Range)
Dim temp1 As String
Dim temp2 As String
Dim temp3 As String

  '  temp1 = replaceList.Offset(0, 0).Value
  '  temp2 = replaceList.Offset(0, 1).Value
  temp1 = "from"
  temp2 = "to"
    multiSub = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(original, temp1, temp2)
End Function
```

If you take the code as it is, then it works, in that it will substitute the word "from" with the word "to" if the first argument in the function I created is pointing to a cell with the word "from" in it somewhere.

If however, I comment out the assignments to temp1 or temp2 and un-comment the other lines, I get a #Value! error in the worksheet.

Interestingly, even if I assign an unrelated variable (say temp3), to one of these range offsets and keep temp1 and temp2 as referring to the hard coded strings, it still fails in the same way.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is Replacelist a horizontal range of two cells?

Comment: Possibly: it is a list that is two horizontally and an arbitrary number vertically. Original on the left and replacement on the right.

Comment: Awe then that is a totally different beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want Cells not Offset as Offset will return a range the same size as the parent range.

```
Function multiSub(original As Range, replaceList As Range)
Dim temp1 As String
Dim temp2 As String
If replaceList.Rows.Count <> 1 Or replaceList.Columns.Count <> 2 Then
    multiSub = "error"
End If

  temp1 = replaceList.Cells(1, 1).Value
  temp2 = replaceList.Cells(1, 2).Value


    multiSub = Replace(original, temp1, temp2)
End Function
```

For your multiple replace:

```
Function multiSub(original As Range, replaceList As Range)

If replaceList.Columns.Count <> 2 Then
    multiSub = "error"
End If

Dim temp1 As Variant
 temp1 = replaceList

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(temp1, 1) To UBound(temp1, 1)
    multiSub = Application.Trim(Replace(" " & original & " ", " " & temp1(i, 1) & " ", " " & temp1(i, 2) & " "))
Next i
End Function
```

This will iterate the rows of a two column range and replace the items in column one with the values in column 2.

Comment: You may want to see the edit for your multi-replace.

Comment: Thanks for this Scott. Can you think of a sensible way to extend this so that it would substitute for whole words only? e.g. I might arrange for "Ed," to be replaced with "Education,", while "Education," wouldn't be replaced with "Educationucation,"
I'm thinking of something RegEx based, but I wonder if Excel has some other tricks up its sleeve for this?

Comment: BTW, your code will be slower as it iterates a range instead of an array.  And using Replace will be quicker than the worksheet formula Substitute.

Comment: Ah, I see how your way is better. I see you have put in a bit to deal with whole words. Words, can end with punctuation though, so a more complex approach is needed here. Perhaps an approach of inserting spaces around punctuation and then re-punctuating at the end would be a work around.

Answer (score 0):

The code I wrote in the end is like this, though it doesn't verify that there are only two columns:

```
Function multiSub(original As Range, replaceList As Range)
Dim temp1 As String
Dim temp2 As String
Dim row As Range

multiSub = original
    For Each row In replaceList.Rows
        multiSub = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(multiSub, row.Cells(1, 1), row.Cells(1, 2))
    Next row
End Function
```

I'll leave Scott's answer as the accepted one as he solved my problem.